# Dividing a picture into N number of equal parts

Tags: algorithm, logic

I need a formula (logic) to divide a fixed area in 'N' number of equal parts. For example I am having a picture/image of 800*800, So now I need to slice it into 10 number of equal parts and what will be the dimension of the sliced portions. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't specify that they need to be square, or impose any other restrictions other than "ten equal parts", why don't you just slice the image into (for your example) ten 80*800 images (or 800*80 if you want to slice in the other dimension)?

That will give ten equal sized chunks without having to worry about whether you have optimal squares and so forth. If the use case is just slicing into equal parts (such as an image coming down the wires from the net, where ten small requests may seem more responsive than one big one), this would work okay.

In other words, something like:

```
def getSlice (sliceNumber, sliceCount, image):
    xpos   = 0
    xsize  = image.xsize

    ypos   =  sliceNumber      * image.ysize / sliceCount
    ypos2  = (sliceNumber + 1) * image.ysize / sliceCount

    if sliceNumber < sliceCount - 1:
        ysize = ypos2 - ypos1
    else:
        ysize = image.ysize - ypos1 - 1

    return image.subImage (xpos, ypos, xsize, ysize)
```

When calling it with five slices, you would get:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|           getSlice (0, 5, image)          |
+-------------------------------------------+
|           getSlice (1, 5, image)          |
+-------------------------------------------+
|           getSlice (2, 5, image)          |
+-------------------------------------------+
|           getSlice (3, 5, image)          |
+-------------------------------------------+
|           getSlice (4, 5, image)          |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

The `ypos/ypos2` stuff and the `if` statement at the end is to cater for situations where the divisions may not give perfectly aligned numbers. They should guarantee that you won't duplicate or miss any lines from the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find for the N all such pairs of k,l that k*l=N. K - num of rows, l - num of columns.
Second, you should choose of these pairs the one you want.
After that you should cut the image.

What step makes a problem?

If you want, for example, the most square parts, check all l's  starting from sqrt(N) down by one. Get the first divider you find. Thus you can combine steps 1 and 2.